# Manifest v3, Failed to load extension: Invalid value for 'web_accessible_resources[0]'. Invalid match pattern. Could not load manifest

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Given this Manifest v3 (after making it work on v2, I've adjusted some specs to match v3), I've some issue when adding the extension into Chrome (load unpacked).

The exact error is:

```
Invalid value for 'web_accessible_resources[0]'. Invalid match pattern.
Could not load manifest.
```

Here is the manifest

```
{
  "author": "Hugo Gresse",
  "description": "",
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "src/entries/contentScript/primary/main.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://play.google.com/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/16.png",
  },
  "permissions": [],
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/16.png",
    },
    "default_popup": "src/entries/popup/index.html"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "assets/src/entries/contentScript/primary/main.5ebc631d.js",
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://play.google.com/console/*"
      ],
      "use_dynamic_url": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the v3 specs specifics to the `web_accessible_resources` [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/), the pattern used in `matches` must only be tld based:

> A list of URL match patterns specifying which pages can access the resources. Only the origin is used to match URLs. Origins include subdomain matching. Paths are ignored.

Update 2023: [`Google Chrome emits an "Invalid match pattern" error if the pattern has a path other than '/*'.`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/)

It says the "paths", here in my case: `console/` is ignored, but it is not as it fail to load the extension.

✅: `https://play.google.com/*`
❌: `https://play.google.com/console/*`

The correct `web_accessible_resources` node is as follows:

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "assets/src/entries/contentScript/primary/main.5ebc631d.js",
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://play.google.com/*"
      ],
      "use_dynamic_url": true
    }
  ]
```

Comment: The documentation is misleading: the paths aren't ignored, but actually prevent installation.

Comment: Documentation and error messaging need fixing by Google. I was going out of my mind there.

Comment: This is still an issue in May 2023, amazingly.

Comment: Somehow I spent half an hour Googling the exact keywords present in this article but this one wasn't in the result. Instead totally irrelevants articles are listed. Only until I make a question on SO that I was led here. And yes, the documentation is updated now: `Google Chrome emits an "Invalid match pattern" error if the pattern has a path other than '/*'.`